# Почему не добавляются данные в MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?php 
$server = "*****"; /* имя хоста (уточняется у провайдера), если работаем на локальном сервере, то указываем localhost */
$username = "****";  // Имя пользователя БД 
$password = "****"; /* Пароль пользователя, если у пользователя нет пароля то, оставляем пустым */
$database = "proxy";
$db_table = "proxy_list";    
$mysqli = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $database);     
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $el = trim($value);
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Ошибка : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
    } else {
        $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO ".$db_table." ('proxy') VALUES('".$el."')");
        var_export($result);
        echo $el;
    }
}
$mysqli->close();
```

Подскажите что не так в запросе, $result выдает false

Comment: `'proxy'` - это строка, а не использование поля `proxy`.

Comment: не понял, нужно убрать кавычки ?

Comment: Именно так и надо сделать.

Comment: Спасибо, как всё просто оказалось )